# Preparing half-dome 360 degree video for vlc or youtube

Tags: 360-panorama, pano-projections

I have a Kodak pixpro sp360. It takes 360x235 degree video. Almost 360 'vr' but the image is dome - not a sphere. I can't create a file that vlc will play using the vr/360 degre playback mode without creating terrible distortion.

The files it records look like this https://youtu.be/rRLw53WmYXM?t=56.

When I open the files in vlc (which supports 360 playback) the files are no 360.

The internet suggested that the mp4 files do not have the required spherical video metadata, and to use google's spherical-media metadata injector, which I did.

https://github.com/google/spatial-media/tree/master/spatialmedia

```
$ python2 -m spatialmedia -i /mnt/DCIM/100SP360/100_0002.MP4 test.mp4
Saved file settings
    Track 0
        Spherical = true
        Stitched = true
        StitchingSoftware = Spherical Metadata Tool
        ProjectionType = equirectangular
    Track 1
```

vlc will now play the test.mp4 in 360 mode but it is projected into a full sphere, not the hemisphere that I expected. The image is distorted and the edge is stitched together. The East and West edges of the dome are joined to form the bottom of the sphere and North and South are stretched.

How can I create a video the vlc and youtube will play using their VR/360 degree players without stretching the dome video to a sphere?

Comment: The equirectangular projection _always_ yields a frame that has an aspect ratio of 2:1. You may need to "fill in" the missing coverage area with black and force the frames of your video to have a 2:1 aspect ratio, before any 360 player will accept it's actually mapped as equirectangular.

Comment: @inkista, I tried that but it didn't work.
I have a fisheye video, spatialmedia was squaring the fisheye without really changing the layout. North, East, South, and West were still Top, Left, Bottm, and Right of the frame. I figured it out though, I used ffmpeg's remap filter to 'unroll' the polar projection to equirectangular. https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/RemapFilter. I wrote a script to generate the pgm files because the included projection.c didn't produce results I liked. I think I'll write up the process and post a detailed answer.

Comment: Cool! Posting an answer would be awesome! Remapping is always relevant to pano stills as well as video.